# Find possible intervals in which the root of a function is found

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, algorithms

I need to apply the bisection method to find the possible roots of the homogeneous equation, $f(x) = 0$, I know how to do the method because it is simple.

The problem is that I need to start from an interval in order to apply this method. So, obviously, the smaller the interval, the less iterations I have to perform.

But I don't know how to find that interval. My Numerical Calculation teacher does something about derivatives, but I'm not sure.

For example, could you do it for the next $f(x)$?

$$f(x) = e^x+3x^4-7x^2$$

Comment: Do you need a guarantee to find all roots (that is difficult in general) ?

Comment: Yes, I need to locate and separate the zeros from the function.

Comment: The fourth derivate is positive for all real $x$, hence we can have at most $4$ roots. Since $3x^4-7x^2=x^2(3x^2-7)>0$ for $|x|\ge 2$, the roots must lies in the interval $[-2,2]$. In fact, we have $4$ roots, which can be seen via $f(-2)>0 , f(-1)<0 , f(0)>0 , f(1)<0 , f(2)>0$. I think you can easily find the roots now.

Comment: I don't understand the part of "Since ... in the interval $[-2,2]$.  Why do you know that?

Comment: $e^x$ is always positive, so if $3x^4-7x^2>0$ , then $f(x)>0$. Therefore for $|x|\ge 2$, $f(x)$ is positive.

Comment: And if it was $-e^{-x}$?

Comment: This is always negative.

Comment: So, I have to derivat until it's always positive, and see where it gets zero?

Comment: Not quite, the derivates allow to determine an upper bound for the number of roots (if you find a derivate always positive or always negative). Working backwards, you can find the roots of the other derivates giving you the intervals where its antiderivate (the previous derivate) increases or decreases. But the method can be cumbersome, and there is no guarantee that it always finds all roots. For functions differntiable arbitary often, there should be no problem.

Comment: If you find a number $m$ such that all derivates are positive at $x=m$, $m$ is an upper bound for the possible roots. If you apply this for $f(-x)$, you get the lower bound $-m$ for the possible roots. This allows you to get an interval containing all roots. Dividing the interval in small partial intervals and look for sign-changes usually finds all roots.

Comment: Could you do it step by step for $g(x)=6x^5-7x^4-6x^3-10x^2+6x-1$, please?

Comment: Not quite easy ; For a polynomial , there are useful theorems, google for example "sturm chain" and "descaretes sign rule". SInce $g(x+2)$ has positive coefficients , $2$ is an upper bound for the roots. Since $g(x-2)$ has alternating signs in the coefficients ,$-2$ is a lower bound of the roots. Hence all roots must lie in the interval $[-2,2]$. Looking at the partial intervals $[-2,-1.9] , [-1.8,-1.7] , ... ,[1.9,2]$ , the only sign change appears in $[1.9,2]$ leading to the root $1.9792\cdots $. Looking at the sturm chain, it can be proven that it is the only real root.

Comment: Just looking at the derivates and determining the monotony-intervals is difficult here because we have degree $5$